# issue with wrapper variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

Apex Controller:

```
 public with sharing class FirstWrapperClass {

    public string w { get; set; }

   //----------Datatypes--------------
   public list<FirstWrapperExample>wrp {get;set;}
   list<FirstWrapperExample> wrp_old = new list<FirstWrapperExample>();
   //------------------DefaultConstructor------------
    Public FirstWrapperClass(){
          wrp = new list<FirstWrapperExample>();
          wrp = getAccounts_in_wrp();
      wrp_old = new list<FirstWrapperExample>();
      wrp_old = getAccounts_in_wrp();
    }

    public list<FirstWrapperExample> getAccounts_in_wrp()
     {
      list<FirstWrapperExample> tempwrp = new list<FirstWrapperExample>();

      list<Account> tempaccountlist = new list<Account>([Select id,name,type,active__c,
       (select id,name,Address_line_2__c,country__c,Landmark__c,pin__c,state__c from Address__r where primary__c=true)from Account
        where Active__c='yes']);
        for(Account accobj:tempaccountlist)
        {
           //create the address instance
           Address__c addrss = new Address__c();
            for(address__c addrssobj : accobj.address__r)
                      addrss = addrssobj;
                      if(accobj.address__r.size()>0)
                      {
                       tempwrp.add(new FirstWrapperExample(accobj,addrss));
                      }
        }
        return tempwrp;
     }
     //----------WrapperClass------------
    Public class FirstWrapperExample{
      public Account account{get;set;}
      public Address__c Add {get;set;}
     //---------------Wrapper Parameterized Constructor--------------------- 
     public FirstWrapperExample(Account a,Address__c ad){

             this.account=a;
             this.Add=ad;
     }

   }

}
```

VF PAGE:

```
<apex:page controller="FirstWrapperClass">
 <apex:form >
 <apex:pageblock >
  <style>
    table.fixed {table-layout:fixed;}
    #td_wp
    {
      font-size:1 em;
      text-align:center;
      padding-top:5px;
      padding-bottom:4px;
      padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
      background-color:#CECEF6;
      color:black;
      border:1px solid #CECEF6;
      }
      #td_row
      {
      font-size:lem;
      border:1px solid #Eoe3e5;
      padding-top:5px;
      padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
      background-color:#cecef6;
      text-align:center
      }
  </style>

    <div style="font-size:1 em;text-align:left;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:4px; background-color:#E0E3E5; color:black;border:1px solid #E0E3E5;">
    <table border="0" class="fixed" style="border-collapse:collapse;width:100%;font-family:rebuchet MS,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">

    <tbody style="display:table-row-group;vertical-align:middle;">
    <tr>
     <td id="td_wp">
       <b>name</b>
       </td>
          <td id="td_wp">
       <b>Active</b>
       </td>
        <td id="td_wp">
       <b>state</b>
       </td>
        <td id="td_wp">
       <b>pin</b>
       </td>
        <td id="td_wp">
       <b>country</b>
       </td>
       </tr>
        <apex:repeat value="{!wrp}" var="W">
        <tr>
        <td id="td_row">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!w.account.id}">{!w.account.name}</apex:outputLink>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </apex:repeat>


       </tbody>
       </table>
    </div>
    </apex:pageblock>
 </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Error:

> Error: Unknown property 'String.account'

Comment: welcome to SFSE, please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. In particular, for your post, reduce the size of the code/markup **to only the essential bits**.  For example, the css is irrelevant. You can use the [edit] link to modify your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `public String` property named `w` declared in the apex class which is not used in the class but conflicting with the `apex:repeat` loop variable  which is also named `w`.

So either change the loop variable name to something else, or remove the property `w` defined in the class.